# Creating multiple files with content from shell

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

New to scripting. How can I write code to create multiple files (a.txt, b.txt, ... , z.txt)?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to put anything in those files?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

One command to create 26 empty files:

```
touch {a..z}.txt
```

or 152:

```
touch {{a..z},{A..Z},{0..99}}.txt
```

A small loop to create 152 files with some contents:

```
for f in {a..z} {A..Z} {0..99}
do
    echo hello > "$f.txt"
done
```

You can do numbered files with leading zeros:

```
for i in {0..100}
do
    echo hello > "File$(printf "%03d" "$i").txt"
done
```

or, in Bash 4:

```
for i in {000..100}
do
    echo hello > "File${i}.txt"
done
```

Answer (score 9):

```
for i in {1..200}; do touch any_prefix_here${i}; done
```

where **i** is the count. So example files are employee**1** employee**2** etc... through to emplyee**200**

Answer (score 4):

To create files with names `a.txt` and `b.txt` simple pass names to `touch`

```
touch a.txt b.txt
```

Comment: This ... is not arbitrary? ;)

Comment: Make sense to fix description :)

Answer (score 3):

```
echo Hello > a.txt
echo World > b.txt

for i in a b c d e f g; do
    echo $i > $i.txt
done
```

If you want more useful examples, ask a more useful question...

Comment: Not everyone is a bash (or shell) expert. It is so easy to do everything with executables it can be easy to forget about built-in flow control tools.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a file using `$ cat > a.txt`. If you need to have a file with specific content, type `$ echo content > filename`.

Answer (score 1):

to have some content in file use dd

```
for i in {1..N};
do
dd if=/dev/urandom of=./path/file${i} bs=1M count=1;
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using filenames a..z i prefer using numbers.

create a script like this (createNfiles.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "" ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 <number of files to create>"
  exit 1
fi

now=`date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S'`
prefix="${now}_myFilePrefix"
echo "creating $1 files"
echo "now=$now"

for i in $(seq 1 $1); do file="${prefix}_${i}.log"; echo "creating $file"; touch $file; done
```

To execute it (create 100 files for example)

> ./createNfiles.sh 100

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr:

```sh
echo CONTENT | tee PATH…
```

---

I had to address the content issue to [create minimal valid Nix files](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/root/-/merge_requests/115), which can't be empty:

```
$ docker run --interactive --rm --tty --volume="${HOME}/dev/root:/etc/nixos" nixos/nix
[…:/# cd /etc/nixos
[…]:/etc/nixos# echo {} | tee common.nix hardware-configuration.nix host.nix
{}
[…]:/etc/nixos# cat common.nix
{}
[…]:/etc/nixos# cat hardware-configuration.nix
{}
[…]:/etc/nixos# cat host.nix
{}
```