# Why is this 4-line bash script not working?

Tags: bash, scripting

Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4141042/226473

I came up with this script:

```
ALT02884% for i in {0..4}
do
  printf "Set for $1" > "$i_directories"
done
```

But it results in the following:

```
zsh: no such file or directory:
zsh: no such file or directory:
zsh: no such file or directory:
zsh: no such file or directory:
zsh: no such file or directory:
```

Answer (score 1):

The shell thinks the underscore is part of the variable name. Use curly braces to tell it to look for a variable named `i` rather than `i_directories`.

```
for i in {0..4}
do
  printf "Set for $1" > "${i}_directories"
done
```